# Make Field.get type-safe with generic type

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to make a `Field.get` call type safe, if the `Type` of the `Field` is `Generic`?

Here is my example (constructor):

```
class SomeClass <T> {
    T someThing;

    public SomeClass(Class<T> someType) {
        try {
            Field field = someType.getField("test");

            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object fieldObj = field.get(someType);

            this.someThing = (T) fieldObj; // Unsafe

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say `Generic` as the type of your field, is that a class named `Generic`, or just a generic class, e.g. `List<T>`? Could you show the whole class?

Comment: A generic class. I will add it, one moment! @cameron1024

Comment: Have added the class @cameron1024

Comment: Normally you can do `someType.cast(fieldObj)` to dynamically cast, given a `Class` object. But I don't understand your logic above it. You are passing a Class object of your type, say `class Foobar`. You are trying to get a reflective handle on field `Foobar.test`. But then you don't have an instance of Foobar, you are trying to get the value of field `Foobar.test` from an instance of class `java.lang.Class`. That doesn't work because that's the wrong type for `Foobar.test`.

Comment: The element I try to access is a static field and it definitly works, because I tested the code above. The only problem ist, that my IDE shows me this usafe cast, thats why I was asking this question. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: In theory, no, could can generally not make it type-safe. Now, since in your specific case it so happens that your field is of the same type as the Class you're inspecting (so it's a class that contains a static field of its own type,) then you can actually use someType.cast()

Comment: Yes it is of the same type as the class. `.cast()` has worked, thank you! Care to write an answer? @kumesana

Comment: @MauriceNino Ok, I didn't know it was a static field. Surprised that it doesn't complain though - to avoid the same confusion for others reading your code, it's best to pass `null` as the argument to `getField` when it's a static field.

Comment: Did not knwo that was a crucial detail. Why `null` in `getField`? @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: If it's not a static field, your code would throw an exception because the type of argument to `get()` is wrong. But for static fields, the Javadoc says "If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null." The object doesn't matter, but if you pass `null` it's clear to the reader that you're accessing a static field. (since it would throw an exception if you pass null and it's not a static field)

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Will do so. @ErwinBolwidt